# How do I merge git users?

Tags: git, merge

How do I merge git users?

I made several commits using an incorrect user name and now they are shown in the repo history, I would like to merge them with my real name that I'm going to use for the git repository.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 6):

I have this script which i use a lot to edit my history. You can just change the name in the if clause or filter by email or anything else:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
        if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "Jimmy McNulty" ];
        then
                GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Jimmy McNulty";
                GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="me@example.com";
                GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Jimmy McNulty";
                GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="me@example.com";
                git commit-tree "$@";
        else
                git commit-tree "$@";
        fi' HEAD
```

Comment: This worked fine for me. It didn't work for me last time when I tried something similar. Thanks!

Comment: Please use this with care. It duplicated all the commits on the branch. Trying to figure out how to go back as I have also pushed it.

Answer (score 0):

If there are just a few commits, you can use interactive rebase and force author and committer each time.

Note, that it will invalidate your branch tip and whatever anyone may have on top of it, so, if you aren't working alone and already pushed your commits somewhere, that's a pain for everyone.

You can also rewrite your history using `git filter-branch` (though you'd have to figure out yourself how to do that and therefore backup stuff first ;-)) (*EDIT*: okay, you don't have to figure that out, perhaps, you can start off of Oin's answer).